# What does multiple edges mean in simple graph definition?

Tags: graph-theory

From [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simple+graph) :

> A simple graph, also called a strict graph, is an unweighted,
>   undirected graph containing no graph loops or `multiple edges`. Unless
>   stated otherwise, the unqualified term "graph" usually refers to a
>   simple graph. A simple graph with multiple edges is sometimes called a
>   multigraph.

What does **multiple edges** mean here ? And does graph loop mean self loops ?

Most reasonable graphs will contain more than one edges. So I am a little bit confused with the term multiple edges.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_edges

Comment: @draks thanks for that link . But I think the term multiple edges is confusing . Parallel edges gives a more intuitive feel of the definition.

Comment: but the edges (shown below) are not parallel...;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\phantom{30 characters for acceptance.......}$[image]

Comment: ...two or more edges that are incident to the same two vertices.

Answer (score 4):

multiple edges are also known as parallel edges. multiple edges are two or more edges that are incident on the same set of two vertices in a graph.